# Remove git history properly without any later reference

Tags: git, commit

I've been doing

```
git push --force origin branch_name
```

without paying any heed recently. But I noticed that although my git repos show exactly how many commits there should be, in my contribution history I can see way more commits. I'm guessing the commits that I've delted after pushing remotely and then doing `push --force` gets in the cycle.

I can get my desired results by deleting the repo in github and then recreating it. But there must be a better way to do this. All I want to do is remove couple of latest commits from git history without any way to reference them later on.

So, my question is how can I permanently delete commits without any way to reference them later on?

Answer (score 0):

First, only [commits from the master branch should be counted](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/).

Second, check if the issue persists over time: there might be a cache effect.

You can check with GitHub support if those extra commits comes from [their reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) of your repo, in which case you can request for that reflog to be purged.

The [OP Enan Ajmain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9429402/enan-ajmain) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50094087/remove-git-history-properly-without-any-later-reference/50094132?noredirect=1#comment87206865_50094132):

> the problem does "go away" with time.
>   And I contacted GitHub help: they told me sometimes they'd have to rebuild contribution graph after a forced push.

Comment: First and second queries are not a problem and I don't really understand what's happening in reflog. I think you misunderstood my question. I want to delete the upstream remote repo and push my local one, which can be done with `push --delete origin branch_name` and `push origin branch_name`. But this gets tedious. I want to know if there is a better way.

Comment: @EnanAjmain What is happening in reglog is that it will keep trakc of old deleted (no longer referenced) commit, which could explain why your contribution graph counts more commits than it should.

Comment: @EnanAjmain the git push --force you mention in your question remains the most direct way to replace a branch history.

Comment: for example, if repo_1 has 10 commits both locally and remotely and I remove the last 9 commits with only one, both local and remote repo shows no. of commits to be 2. But my contribution graph shows 11 commits, so I think it includes my deleted commits! Now, if I delete the origin/master branch and push again from my local repo, my contribution graph shows 2 commits as it should. Why?

Comment: @EnanAjmain "But my contribution graph shows 11 commits, so I think it includes my deleted commits!" Again, I suspect this is because of the reflog on the GitHub repo side. Contact GitHub support for confirmation.

Comment: I wanted to let you know, the problem does "go away" with time. And I contacted github help and they told me sometimes they'd have to rebuild contribution graph after a forced push. Do you know how I can myself rebuild my contribution graph?

Comment: @EnanAjmain That I don't know: GitHub support would be better suited to answer that question.